# Select the complete row of a maximum value column

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

The situation is , I have a table which has for example 10 rows.
I want to calculate the value of 'price' column and want to select the complete row ehich has MAX price.

```
var offer = (from p in dc.CustomerOffer
                                 join q in dc.OffersInBranch
                                     on p.ID equals q.OfferID
                                 where q.BranchID == singleLoc.ID
                                 select (p.OriginalPrice - p.NewPrice) * 100 / p.OriginalPrice).Max();
```

The above code gives me only the MAX price, How would I select the whole row.
Any ideas guys??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
var offer = (from p in dc.CustomerOffer
                                 join q in dc.OffersInBranch
                                     on p.ID equals q.OfferID
                                 where q.BranchID == singleLoc.ID
            let value = (p.OriginalPrice - p.NewPrice) * 100 / p.OriginalPrice
            order by value desc
                                 select p).First()
```

Note : This is a dummy code and it might not be syntactically correct. You might have to tweak the query as per your requirement.